# Jquery HTML5 CSS3 Help Needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, host

I am using a HTML5 CSS3 jquery template (vivid photo) that I have modified greatly and everything works GREAT on my computer(local host).... I also integrated colorbox jquery.

However, as soon as I uploaded it to a server online, The popup javascript for the navigation menu is not working, and I believe on IE9, the bottom image bar is not loading...

Here it is:
http://tinyurl.com/89lst8j

Any help? I am not that good at programming, but I am good at trial and error and manipulation of scripts... I am just confused that if it works on my local host... it must be something with the online server that is not working right??

Please help if you can, thanks!

http://pritesh.info/vivid-photo-2/
Here was  the template I modified which looks like it works... I just added more pop-up commands for several more navigational items and added colorbox... not much else between swapping content.

Comment: So a popup is supposed to appear when a link is clicked in the nav?

Comment: A popup does appear when you click "Performer Registration"

Comment: Sorry... the "Performer Registration" is from the colorbox jquery and colorbox is working fine... but you are correct... a type of popup just like color box is suppose to pop up when clicking on any of the navigational items... also at the very bottom is suppose to be 8 images that have youtube colorbox links... and although they work for me in Firefox/safari, they are not showing in IE9 for others. I would post the scripts I am using, but if they are working correctly on my local host.. there should be nothing wrong with them[?].. I can post any coding if anyone thinks it may help!

Comment: I would put a `console.log("I was clicked");` on the click event of the nav items, perhaps the click event isn't triggering

Comment: When you said it worked on localhost, did it work in IE9 on localhost?

Comment: Worked previewing localy in firefox and chrome.. havnt tried IE9 localhost as I dont have it on this computer.   where in what script should I put the console.log("I was clicked");  ?  Sorry, not very familiar with scripts but learned fast over the past 2 days

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have some javascript errors on line 95 in your functions.js on page load. This prevents any furhter execution of other javascript code on page load. Probably this breaks your navigation menu popup.

the footer navigation seems to not work in ie nor in firefox (expanded footer pane is empty).
However, the navigation (image) bar is loading in both browsers, ff and ie9.

To test your websites in different browsers you may install IETester or a similar tool (e.g. spoon.net). In Firefox you can use Firebug to look behind the scenes.

Off the topic but may be of interest for you:
You do a lot of requests downloading more than 2MB which is quite a lot for an initial page load. You could increase the performance of your site by reducing the amount of requests.

Comment: Hmm... I never edited that script, it came with the template, not sure what is wrong with line 95:                      var containerWidth = lastElem[0].offsetLeft + lastElem.outerWidth() + 2*extra;                                                            I will check out cross compatible broser tools... I used chrome and firefox to preview via local host, dont have ie9 on this computer.  Wierd thing is the footer navigation works fine for me in firefox... I am assuming it is a javascript error that results from online loading vs previewing thru saved on my computer. no idea where to begin